# Possible to set a Cp_Model constraint in terms of the sum of maxima of different variables/linear expressions?

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I need to express a constraint in terms of a sum of maxima. I'm aware it's no longer a linear problem but I'm hoping that there's a way to fake or approximate it somehow:

```py
model = cp_model.CpModel()

foo = {x: model.NewBoolVar(f"var{x}") for x in range(1, 6)}
bar = {x: model.NewBoolVar(f"var{x}") for x in range(6, 11)}

model.Add(
    sum(max(k * v for k, v in variables.items()) for variables in [foo, bar]) <= 20
)
# NotImplementedError: Evaluating a BoundedLinearExpr as a Boolean value is not supported.
```

The error is that you can't call `max()`:

```py
max(k * v for k, v in foo.items())
# NotImplementedError: Evaluating a BoundedLinearExpr as a Boolean value is not supported.
```

Faking `max()` with `log(sum(exp(...), ...))` doesn't work because `log()` fails:

```py
log(sum(int(exp(k)) * v for k, v in foo.items()))
# TypeError: must be real number, not _SumArray
```

As does converting `log(sum(...)` into `sum(prod(...))`:

```py
prod(sum(int(exp(k)) * v for k, v in variables.items()) for variables in [foo, bar])
# TypeError: Not an integer linear expression: ((((((403 * var6)) + (1096 * var7)) + (2980 * var8)) + (8103 * var9)) + (22026 * var10))
```

Full code listing:

```py
from functools import reduce
from math import log, exp
import operator as op
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

def prod(args):
    return reduce(op.mul, args)

model = cp_model.CpModel()

foo = {x: model.NewBoolVar(f"var{x}") for x in range(1, 6)}
bar = {x: model.NewBoolVar(f"var{x}") for x in range(6, 11)}

model.Add(
    sum(max(k * v for k, v in variables.items()) for variables in [foo, bar]) <= 20
)
# NotImplementedError: Evaluating a BoundedLinearExpr as a Boolean value is not supported.

max(k * v for k, v in foo.items())
# NotImplementedError: Evaluating a BoundedLinearExpr as a Boolean value is not supported.

log(sum(int(exp(k)) * v for k, v in foo.items()))
# TypeError: must be real number, not _SumArray

prod(sum(int(exp(k)) * v for k, v in variables.items()) for variables in [foo, bar])
# TypeError: Not an integer linear expression: ((((((403 * var6)) + (1096 * var7)) + (2980 * var8)) + (8103 * var9)) + (22026 * var10))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. max() from python is interpreted before the Add() method is called. The result is unpredictable, and just wrong.
2. The solver is integral only, so any trick using math double functions will just not work.

just use the `model.AddMaxEquality()` method documented [here](http://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#cp_model.CpModel.AddMaxEquality).

In is used in many examples of the distribution, including this [one](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b37d9c786b69128f3505f15beca09e89bf078a89/examples/python/gate_scheduling_sat.py#L108).

Note that MaxArray takes an array of variables. So you will need to create intermediate variables for all terms in max equation.

Comment: Didn't realize the constraint target could itself be a variable. This works great, thank you!